# Css hover not working when try to create sample hover

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make very sample animation when hover, but i still don't know why it not work,
Here is the react code:

```
export default function Dropdown() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.containerDropdown}>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is css :

```
.containerDropdown {
 
  border: 3px rgb(49, 59, 49) solid;
  transition: border 1s ease;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.containerDropdown :hover {
  border: 3px rgb(8, 95, 8) solid;
}
```

It do not make any change if i hover to that component
[image]

Comment: .containerDropdown:hover{border: 3px rgb(8, 95, 8) solid;}

Comment: Remove space between :hover and selector

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the space after .containerDropdown

```
.containerDropdown:hover{
  border: 3px rgb(8, 95, 8) solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove space between :hover and selector**

```
.containerDropdown:hover
    {
      border: 3px rgb(8, 95, 8) solid;
    }
```